# creating a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
a <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(c('gr1','','','','gr2','','','','','gr3','','',
                        rep(1,12),rep(2,12)),ncol=3)))
```

`a` looks like:

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11 V12
    gr1             gr2                 gr3      
     1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
     2  2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
```

Columns V1-V4 belong to gr1, V5-V9 to gr2, and V10-V12 to gr3.

I would like to separate these groups (gr1-gr3) and their corresponding columns and put them all in a list that I can later on loop and do some analysis. So the desired output is:

`list1 = (gr1,gr2,gr3)`, where each of gr1, gr2, and gr3 are a dataframe with their corresponding columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a grouping variable based on whether the first row element is blank (`''`) or not.  Then, `split` the column names of 'a' with the 'grp' to a `list` and then `subset` the columns and rows (remove the first row) using `lapply`, change the `names` of the 'lst' as the 'gr' values that we extract the first row of 'a'.

```
grp <- cumsum(as.character(unlist(a[1,]))!='')
lst <- lapply(split(names(a), grp),  function(nm) a[-1, nm])

nm1 <- as.character(unlist(a[1,]))
names(lst) <-  nm1[nzchar(nm1)]
```

NOTE: The columns in 'a' are `factor` class due to the presence of the second header ('gr') as the first row.  If we need to convert the columns in each data.frame in the 'lst' to numeric,

```
 lapply(lst, function(x) {
      x[] <- lapply(x, function(.x) as.numeric(as.character(.x)))
      x})
```